# What happens to Teams chats/discussion when an AD user is deleted and re-added?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, microsoft-teams

I am experiencing mailbox issues with a user account in Office 365. My users are sync'd from my on-premise Active Directory using the Azure AD Connect application. I think I can resolve the issue by:

- moving the on-premise user to an OU that is not sync'd to Azure
- resync to Azure AD
- completely delete the user in Azure AD
- move the on-premise user back to its correct OU
- resync Azure AD
- reassign licenses

There is not much data associated with this user. There is no mailbox data or OneDrive files. There are, however, chats and discussions in Teams. Would the process listed above affect the chats/discussions in Teams for this user? Would the previous chats/discussions be attributed to the resync'd user account?

Comment: Post your mailbox problem and maybe we can help with that. Also, Office 365 support is free. Have you considered opening a support case from your Tenant portal for the mailbox problem?

Comment: Thank you, @joeqwerty. I opened a ticket for the mailbox issue three days ago. It was escalated to the engineering team, but I was told support would be delayed due to the massive influx of new users due to covid-19. I'm trying to work around the issue, as the first layer of support was baffled by certain parts of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When deleted, the user's chats/conversations are lost, and the user is removed from all teams. Channel discussions are left intact, but they are not linked/attributed to the recreated user.